# how to convert string json inside a valid json into valid json python

Tags: python, json, string

I have a json which contains string json:

```
{"id":1 , 
"name": "John",
"string_info": "{\"color\":\"blue\", \"age\":"\24\"}"
}
```

How can I convert string_into into a valid json so the whole json will be just valid json like below:

```
{"id":1 , 
"name": "John",
"string_info": {"color":"blue", "age":"24"}
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: use `json.loads`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `json.loads()` on the string_info value.